# Hacer aparecer el teclado cuando usuario hace touch en un botón

Tags: android, edittext, touch

Espero me puedan ayudar, estoy intentando hacer que cuando el usuario toque una determinada área que está por encima de un `EditText`, se le pase el foco a dicho `EditText`, y este funcione como debería funcionar.

Actualmente lo que probé fué lo siguiente:

```
// ed es el EditText en cuestión
// l es el layout que tengo encima del EditText
final Context c = getContext();
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) c.getSystemService(c.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

l.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        imm.showSoftInput(ed, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        ed.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        ed.requestFocus();

        return true;
    }
});
```

Pero mi problema es que, cuando toco el área `layout`, y el teclado se despliega, el `EditText` no recibe lo que se escribe en el teclado, tampoco este se oculta cuando se presiona la tecla done, solo se oculta cuando se presiona el botón físico back.

Y estoy atascado en esto...
Gracias de antemano.

**Pruebas**

Probé según lo que me comentaron de la siguiente forma:

```
// ed es el EditText en cuestión
// l es el layout que tengo encima del EditText
final Context c = getContext();

l.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

        ed.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        ed.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) c.getSystemService(c.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);

        return true;
    }
});
```

**Resultado:**

Al **1er touch**, el teclado no se abre, al **2do touch** el teclado se abre y se cierra, esto se repite sucesivamente, supongo que hay que manejar que el teclado se abra o cierre dependiendo de si está cerrado/abierto, pero si al **1er touch** el teclado no se abre, quedo igual... ya que tampoco el texto del teclado llega al `EditText`.

Seguiré investigando esto.
Gracias

Comment: La solución no va en la pregunta, elimínala de ahí y por favor publícala abajo en la zona de respuestas

Comment: listo, ya la publiqué como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

La solución era, habilitar el botón.

Habilitar el botón...

```
ed.setEnabled(true); // ed es el EditText
```

*Capa 8*

Espero que esto no solo me sirva de lección a mi.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Intenta esto dentro de un bloque try-catch.
Suerte

Comment: Por favor explica tu código, las respuestas que son solo scripts generalmente se consideran de baja calidad; pues no indican como integrarse a la pregunta ni por que resuelven el problema

Comment: Claro, mi error, el metodo anterior sirve para forzar la aparición del keyboard en pantalla, por lo tanto en vez de utilizar tu metodo, solo haces un request focus a tu edit text
``EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
editText.requestFocus();``
 Y luego de eso utilizas el pedazo de código que compartí antes

Comment: No me funciona, de hecho, no se muestra el teclado usando `imm.toggleSoftInput` después de hacer el `requestFocus` del `EditText`. Y si vuelvo a presionar, el teclado se muestra y se oculta y así con cada toque que le doy al layout.